# Clarification what is web content management in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: content, wcm

It might be simple and stupid question however I would like to know what is the definition of web content management in sharepoint 2010?

Shall we say, we are using web content management in sharepoint 2010 if we uses only the list and library to store the contents(items or documents)...I guess, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCM generally refers to publishing features in that you are managing the authoring and publication of web pages. This could include things like creating customized page layouts for publishing content types and approval workflow processes for approving content people are authoring.